# Android AppUpdateManager doesn't finish IMMEDIATE update

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update

I'm implementing AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE in-app-updates from Play Market using this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

When I test I can't finish update process - it just throws me back to old app where I get prompted to update again and again.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SplashActivity.kt
private fun checkAppUpdate() {
    val appUpdateManager = getUpdateManager()
    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
        ) {
            showError("Update available. You should update")
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                this,
                UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            viewModel.loadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I should listen to apk download and start installing manually?

Comment: Did this resolve on its own? I had something like this happen where Google Play was just not serving the download.  The in-app update window would say "download pending...", then close, then nothing would happen.  ~36 hours later it started working again randomly